# Evaluate $\int_{2\pi m} ^{2\pi n} \sqrt{1+\sin^2(x)} dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, numerical-methods

$$\int_{2\pi m} ^{2\pi n}  \sqrt{1+\sin^2(x)} dx$$  where $m,n \in {\rm I\!R}$

I understand that the function is equivalent to the incomplete elliptic integral of the second kind https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_integral#Incomplete_elliptic_integral_of_the_second_kind
but how do you use numerical methods to solve this integral with the given limits and keeping the variables of m and n?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With $k \in \mathbb R$
$$I(k)=\int_{0}^{k\pi} \sqrt{1+ \sin^2 (x)} \,dx$$ $$I(k)=2 \,\text{IntegerPart}[k]\, E(-1)+E(\pi\,  \text{FractionalPart}(k)|-1)$$

For example
$$I\left(\frac{33}{10}\right)=6 E(-1)+E\left(\left.\frac{3 \pi }{10}\right|-1\right)$$

If you need an approximation of
$$E\left(\left.\alpha \pi \right|-1\right) \qquad \text{with} \qquad 0<\alpha < 1$$ you could use the series expansion
$$E\left(\left.\alpha \pi \right|-1\right)=E(-1)+t-\frac{t^3}{24}+\frac{t^5}{384}+\frac{11 t^7}{322560}-\frac{11
   t^9}{18579456}+O\left(t^{11}\right)$$ where $t=\sqrt{2} \pi  \left(\alpha -\frac{1}{2}\right)$

**Edit**

For small values of $\alpha$, use
$$E\left(\left.\alpha \pi \right|-1\right)=\pi  \alpha +\frac{\pi ^3 }{6}\alpha ^3-\frac{7 \pi ^5 }{120}\alpha ^5+O\left(\alpha ^7\right)$$ and for $\alpha$ close to $1$, use
$$E\left(\left.\alpha \pi \right|-1\right)=2 E(-1)+\pi  (\alpha -1)+\frac{\pi ^3 }{6} (\alpha -1)^3-\frac{7\pi ^5}{120} 
   (\alpha -1)^5+O\left((\alpha -1)^7\right)$$

Answer (score 1):

Since the integrand is periodic with a period $\pi$ the is integral becomes
$$I=4\pi(n-m)\int_{0}^{\pi} \sqrt{1+ \sin^2 x} dx=8(n-m)E(-1).$$
where $E(-1)$ is the  elliptic integral.

Comment: The question says $n, m \in \mathbb R$

Comment: Today the questions are not readable. There is also $I$ in it.